# Move items in UIelementCollection

Tags: c#, collections, uwp

I have the given collection with this order (original).

| Item name | original index |
| --- | --- |
| Item A | 0 |
| Item B | 1 |
| Item C | 2 |
| Item D | 3 |
| Item E | 4 |

I want to reorder it following the updated index

| Item name | original index | updated index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Item A | 0 | 4 |
| Item B | 1 | 0 |
| Item C | 2 | 1 |
| Item D | 3 | 3 |
| Item E | 4 | 2 |

Im using the [Move](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.uielementcollection.move?view=winrt-22000) method that moves an item at the specified index to a new location in the collection which is perfect since I dont need to remove/clear then re add items to the tree.

If I move only one item, the item is placed where it belongs. If I move all the items where they need to be using a loop, at some point I will move an item I have already previously moved to its new position into a bad position.

```
foreach (MyItem item in newOrderedItems)
     {
          if (ItemsSourceUpdated)
               Panel.Children.Move((uint)item.OriginalIndex, (uint)item.UpdatedIndex);
          else
               Panel.Children.Move((uint)item.UpdatedIndex, (uint)item.OriginalIndex);
     }
```

How can I avoid that behavior ?

Comment: since you move all the items, why not clear the collection and re-add them with specific index?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I want to avoid that as much as possible to prevent my UI to blink when clearing and avoid to rebuild the elements inside. Move() by itself does what I need perfectly. So I dont want to remove or clear and then re add elements.

Comment: You could extend bool property for item, set it as true then item moved. before move next one, please check it's ismoved property.